# Press button when class name changes using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium for Edge what would the proper syntax be to click the div below? the class names changes but the "Run Job" text remains the same. How can I click on this using the text instead of the class?

```
<div class="x9f619 xjbqb8w x78zum5 x168nmei x13lgxp2 x5pf9jr xo71vjh x1n2onr6 x1plvlek xryxfnj x1iyjqo2 x2lwn1j xeuugli xdt5ytf xqjyukv x1qjc9v5 x1oa3qoh x1nhvcw1">Run Job</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `xpath`

```
button= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Run Job']")
```

Now click on this.

```
button.click()
```

***OR*** using the explicit wait

```
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("your_website_url_here")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

button= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Run Job']")))

button.click()
driver.quit()
```

***import***

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: This works but seems like I am having issues pressing the next button. there are certain instances when I may need to stop the job and the text has an apostrophe.  How would I press "Stop Leo's Job" the class value changes as well

Comment: Can you add that one as a separate new question and add the detail there like `code` , `Error` and `HTML` source

Comment: here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78000614/press-button-when-class-name-changes-using-selenium-and-the-text-has-an-apostrop