# Press button when class name changes using Selenium and the text has an apostrophe

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This is a similar question to a prior question but the previous method wont work if the text has an apostrophe in the string. I need to click the this class with changing value.

```
<div class="x1g731 xwtio9w y99xum8 x168nmei x13lgxp2 x5pf9jr xo71vjh r7s2etuq x1plvlek xstyops x1iyjqo2 x2lwn1j xeuugli xdt5ytf xqjyukv x1qjc9v5 x1oa3qoh x1nhvcw1">Stop Leo's job</div>
```

Tried to run

```
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Stop Leo\'s Job']")))
button.click()
```

But this wont work seems the escape sequence is not working.

Comment: so whats your problem? where is your code?

Comment: Thank you Wonka I should have made that more clear.

Comment: try this triple double-quote: """//div[text()="Stop Leo's Job"]"""

Comment: Also probably dupe question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822153/escape-single-quote-in-xpath-with-nokogiri

Comment: That was the answer. It worked Thank you. Did you want to create a formal answer so you can get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this triple double-quote:

```
"""//div[text()="Stop Leo's Job"]"""
```